# how to access multi array json file?

Tags: android

this is my code below how do i acess this json file  check my method it is coreect method to aces json file array and nodes? i want to acess this json file below from my code help me how do i acess this json file formmy code? i dontknow howmany array in json file

```
{
    "status":1,
    "message":"",
    "data":
    {
        "school":
        [
        {
            "id":3,
            "name":"FG Public School"
        },
        {
            "id":4,
            "name":"Fazaia Inter College"}
        ]
    }
}




HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);

HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(SelectMenuAPI);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
InputStream atomInputStream = 
response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

String line;
String str = "";
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
    str += line;
}


JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("school");

for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object =  
    data.getJSONObject(i); 

    //    JSONObject category = 
    object.getJSONObject("Category");


    Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(object.getString("id")));

    Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));

    Log.d("Category name", 
    Category_name.get(i));
```

Comment: is not display this code checkmy json code please "school" is aray or node????

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Please make sure you posted the entire loop.

Comment: school is an array.. every element of the array is a node

Comment: @user2644835 first fetch the **data** object value then, fetch the school array values.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This Code
=================================================================
    try {
            String[] Id,name;
          JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);

          JSONObject SubString3 = json.getJSONObject("data");
          Log.e(SubString3.toString(),"SubString3");
          JSONArray Array = SubString3.getJSONArray("school");
          Id = new String[Array.length()];
          name =new String[Array.length()]; 
          for(int i=0;i<=Array.length();i++)
          {
              Id[i]= Array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
              Log.e(Id[i].toString(),"Id[i]");
              name[i]= Array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
              Log.e(name[i].toString(),"name[i]");
          }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: where u used string 1 and string 2??

Comment: Substring1 And Substring2 store just String Of Status and Message Its Just Parsing.

Comment: See i Update My Answer I hope You got your Answer.

Comment: not working answer here plz i paste my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055689/json-filenot-show-on-listview-help-me

Answer (score 1):

The Category object is not present inside the Json file

you can try following

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject("str");
    JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
    JSONArray school = json.getJSONArray("school");

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = school.getJSONObject(i);

        long id = Long.parseLong(object.getString("id"));
        String name = object.getString("name");
        JSONObject category = new JSONObject();
                    category.put("id");
                    category.put("name");




    }
```

Comment: i wantto add  incategory object then load in listview

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fetch an OBJECT of the whole JSON because it's in '{' '}'. Then you need to fetch an object again with the name "data" because it is in '{' '}'. And only then should you fetch the array named "school".

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray school = data.getJSONArray("school");
```